# Impact of enabling C#7 support?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, c#-7.0

Two separate workstations both using VS2015 are compiling the same codebase. The projects target .Net 4.6.1. One workstation builds, the other reports build errors on a get property accessor using => syntax. The suggestion popping up in VS is to enable C#7 support. What impact does enabling C#7 support have on the project/solution files? Is there a risk to deployment? Or is it simply how the compiler interprets the code and the generated MSIL assemblies are identical? Is C#7 a separate nu-get package or VS extension? I'm guessing this is all fine and simply an environmental setting with no change to the codebase or deployed assemblies, but I'd like to be sure. Is it caused by one of the machines also having VS2017 installed?

Comment: "Is it caused by one of the machines also having VS2017 installed?" Well that would mean that the C# 7 compiler is installed, yes. If you want to use C# 7, I'd recommend using VS2017 on both machines. Otherwise even if you can get everything to build etc, you're still not going to have a great experience in VS2015.

Comment: Thank you @JonSkeet I guess I'm still thinking of the compiler being part of the framework and running off the same CLI regardless of the IDE that is being used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C# 7 has impact during compilation but in the end the output is the same. Moving to C# 7 implies upgrading all your tools implied in the process of building your assemblies (on our side we had to upgrade developpers computers and our continuous integration platform)